# Regex for this date format?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to find a regex that will match dates in the following format: **3-Jul-16** or **30-Jun-16**

I have tried this regex at first:

```
/[0-9]{1,}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{1,}/g
```

But it matches also dates like **947-UfO-104**, and this is not something I want.
First, I got the month:

```
/[0-9]{1,}-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-[0-9]{1,}/g
```

Now, the year is fine, because it could be anything numerical.
For the day part, I have tried:

```
/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30|31)-(Jan|Feb.../g
```

Now, my problem is that when given something like that: **73-Jul-2015**
It matches: **3-Jul-2015**

I tried making sure that the date is followed by a non-digit char like that:

```
/[^0-9]{1,}([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30|31)-(Jan|Feb.../g
```

But then, when the date is at the beggining of the string, it didn't catch it (because it's not followed by **any** char).

So my question is, is there a regex part that says **"An non-numerical char or empty string"**?

Comment: *"Im kinda new with regex, but I want to learn more"* - great! *"so I need a regex search"* - nope. Start with e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the task into 3 parts. First, a number in the range of 1-31 ([tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)), then a list of possible values for the month, and then two numbers.

```
\b([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\d{2})\b
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI3eO8/3)

Comment: @Rommel I hope you learned more about regex from this example. It's not okay to take an answer without learning how to do it yourself.

Comment: @4castle when fed with `35-Jul-12` it catches `5-Jul-12`, please take note!

Comment: @YotamSalmon Good call. Fixed that with word-break assertions.